# KDB - Filter List Column Based on Another Column

Tags: kdb

I'm struggling with eliminating data from my query.  I have attached a picture with my data results (data itself is too large and has customer info so I can't include).  I have two tables that I'm joining by SKU to show when we enter a SKU into the system and when we sell it.  We reuse SKUs based on vendors which isn't the best practice but is currently a necessity.  What I'd like to do is eliminate the InvoiceDates where InvoiceDate < TransferDate.  So in the InvoiceDate column it would only show the highlighted yellow dates for the first few rows.

Please let me know if you have any questions and thanks for the help!

[image: Data Result]

Comment: What do you mean by elimindate invoice dates where invoiceDate? Do you want to delete the row if a particular invoceDate is present in invoiceDate column of that row?

Comment: Sorry, my formatting was bad so it ignored the part.  I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
 q) update InvoiceDate:{x where x >= y}'[InvoiceDate;TransferDate] from tbl
```

**Explanation:**

Above query uses 'each-both(') function to iterate over InvoiceDate and TransferDate values pair wise(indirectly row wise), pass each pair to lambda function as 'x' and 'y' and then  select 'x'(InvoiceDate) which are >= 'y'(TransferDate)

Comment: Thanks!  This works great.  Definitely going to need to learn more about this each-both function as I feel it could help me a lot.  I found this paper, do you know of other resources for teaching myself more about this and similar concepts?  Thanks again!     https://code.kx.com/q/wp/efficient_use_of_adverbs.pdf

Comment: Adverbs are higher order functions which are very useful. You can read details about them on KX wiki: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/

Comment: One issue I'm having is that I can't export the result to a .csv.  The issue seems to be with the InvoiceDate column.  If I delete that column the export works fine however with the column included I get a Type error on the save command.  I can export the selection from QPad to a csv without issue.   Do you know why I can't save it down through KDB?  I'm using the save command `$"C:/q/tbl.csv"` Thanks!

Comment: Thats because 'save' does not support nested structure and invoceDate is nested type. For that you have to convert values of invoiceDate to string and then save it. Ex: t:update invoiceDate:" " sv' string invoiceDate from t; save `t.csv.  Also when you read this table back, you will have to cast invoiceDate back to 'date' type.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You question is cut off, but I'm guessing you want to filter on whether a particular date is in your invoiceDate lists.  You can do this as follows:

`q)select from tbl where in[2019.01.01;] each invoiceDate`

If this isn't what you are looking for, please clarify above with an example

Comment: Sorry, the formatting was bad so it cut off the question.  I fixed it above but my question is to eliminate only the dates in the InvoiceDate column that are after the TransferDate.  So it would only show the highlighted yellow data.